# Saving to file in Lisp

Tags: file-io, lisp, common-lisp

I'm just trying to write to a file with the following function:

```
(defun test-save ()
  (with-open-file (stream "test.txt" :if-does-not-exist :create)
                  (format stream "success!")))
```

However, entering in `(test-save)` generates the following stuff:
[image: errors galore]

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Cusp for Eclipse with SBCL on a Mac, if it matters.

UPDATE: now this new error:
[image: new error]

And the repl:

```
COMMON-LISP-USER>
(with-open-file (stream "test.txt" :direction :output
                                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
      (format stream "success!"))

error opening #P"/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/test.txt":
  File exists
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]
    0: [ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
    1: [TERMINATE-THREAD] Terminate this thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" {12539CB1}>)
]> 0
```

UPDATE 2:

Solved! I just had to use `:if-exists :supersede`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `:direction :output` to create an output file stream:

```
(with-open-file (stream "test.txt" :direction :output
                                   :if-does-not-exist :create)
      (format stream "success!"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's gotten a little better now (new error), but still no luck. What else would you recommend?